# django template does not render complete context

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am using templates with django. I am having a problem where the Context is not being rendered. The meta_k is null. The meta_description is not.

```
 t = get_template('projects.html')   
 html = t.render(Context({
       'completed': completed, 
       'current':current, 
       'description': sp.description, 
       'project_title':sp.name, 
       'img':images, 
       'meta_desc': sp.meta_description, 
       'meta_k:': sp.meta_keywords
 }))
```

I can start the server in debug mode in eclipse and So I know sp.meta_keywords is not null. Here is where I call the code in projects.html:

```
{% block meta_keywords %}<br>
{% if meta_k %}<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ meta_k }}<br>
{% else %}<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Venkat, Rao, engineer, inventor, entrepreneur, projects, blue dart, control systems, labview<br>
{% endif %}<br>
{% endblock %}
```

This defaults to the else when I know meta_k should not be null. The complete code can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/personal-site423/source/browse/) on Google Code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the result is an empty string or empty list, or anything that evaluates to `False` in Python, including `None`, it will enter the else part.

Comment: I know the result is not empty or None as I see values for the variable in the watch window

Comment: most probably it is error in your code then in django, can try passing sp to context and print out values in projects.html, so you can be sure what values are coming?

Comment: Can you show a standalone django code which depicts the problem and can be run on command line, if you try that either you will find the problem or we will get to see the bug

Comment: so i do this and it works: html = t.render(Context({'sp': sp})) then in project.html I change it to: {% if sp %}
 {{ sp.meta_keywords}}
{% else %}
 Venkat, Rao, engineer, inventor, entrepreneur, projects, blue dart, control systems, labview
{% endif %} and this works

Comment: why should the other way not work?

Comment: what is sp.meta_keywords ? dict or ?

Comment: sp.meta_keywords is TextProperty from google app engine

Comment: i have meta_desc which is also a TextProperty and I use it in the template almost the exact same way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I was just making stupid mistake:

In the rendering file I have:

```
html = t.render(Context({'completed': completed, 'current':current, 'description': sp.description, 'project_title':sp.name, 'img':images, 'meta_desc': sp.meta_description, 'meta_k:': sp.meta_keywords)
```

this refers to "meta_k:" **note the semicolon**

in the template I have

```
{% if meta_k %}
```

**note no semicolon**

If I remove the semicolon it works. That was stupid.

Comment: yes mostly it is, that is why if you try to make problem simpler and pinpoint the area where the problem is eventually you will find the reason, otherwise staring at a complex bunch of code and thinking seems like a bug in django doesn't help

Answer (score 3):

Only suggestion for you is that most probably it is bug in your code, for us it will be difficult to debug without running your whole project.

So i suggest you experiment on command line and see if you can replicate the bug in simple steps, so that we can try to fix it. I am sure in the process you will find the problematic part

e.g. I see your template rendered correctly by my simple context

```
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> s = """{% block meta_keywords %}<br>
... {% if meta_k %}<br>
... &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ meta_k }}<br>
... {% else %}<br>
... &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Venkat, Rao, engineer, inventor, entrepreneur, projects, blue dart, control systems, labview<br>
... {% endif %}<br>
... {% endblock %}"""
>>> t = Template(s)
>>> c = Context({'meta_k':['a','b','c']})
>>> t.render(c)
u'<br>\n<br>\n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[&#39;a&#39;, &#39;b&#39;, &#39;c&#39;]<br>\n<br>\n'
```

Comment: Possible reasons: As  `{% if meta_k %}` branch is not getting executed means meta_k somehow evaluate to False, either meta_k is empty or a object which is evaluating to false, try passing "%s"%sp.meta_keywords instead and see what is the result